# Spring boot: how to validate 2 optional date parameters are provided as soon as one is provided?

Tags: spring-boot, controller

From a spring boot controller, i'm wondering what is the pattern to follow to verify 2 optional date parameters can't be null as soon as one is provided. in other words, they can be null or both of them filled

```
public ResponseEntity<CardResponse> getCards(
            @RequestParam(required = false) String orderReference,
            @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime orderPlacementDateStart,
            @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime orderPlacementDateEnd,
            @PageableDefault(page = DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER, size = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) Pageable pageRequest) {

}
```

I saw some class-level constraints but i'm not sure if i can apply it on 2 different params ?

Please tell me what is recommended in this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am answering because I can't comment. I'd recommend combining all these parameters into a POJO and using bean validation to check for validity of request parameters. To validate two fields together, you could try a nested object. See [this blog post](http://dolszewski.com/spring/how-to-bind-requestparam-to-object/) with examples. This will provide a course-grained approach that is more maintainable and readable.

Comment: A custom validator might help here --> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator.